# Overriding a method, but an exception must be thrown

Tags: java, exception

I'm writing a code for an assignment. For the assignment, there are methods with return types that aren't void that must be overrided and I must decide whether or not they are allowed to occur. If they are not allowed, then that overrided method must throw an exception. I'm not allowed to just delete the said method. Not sure what's the purpose of this exercise is, but it's an assignment nonethelss. With all of this in mind my code for methods that are not allowed looks something like this:

```
public (some return type) method () {
    if(true)
        throw new (Some exception here);
    return (the corresponding return type)
}
```

I'm just forcibly throwing an exception. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: get rid of the `if(true)` and `return` statements and just do `throw new UnsupportedOperationException();` This is what some implementations of List actually do when for example you would try to call add() on an immutable List http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29

Comment: It's reasonable to forcibly throw the exception. If the method is not supported at all in the implementation class, the method implementation can consist of nothing but the `throw` statement. For the exception, one possibility is `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Make sure that you add an `@throws` line to the Javadoc comment of the method. (Because you are rigorous about writing Javadoc comments, of course. All Java programmers are, or else they're not really programmers.)